# Using 'or' in Prolog

Tags: prolog

For some reason, these two pieces of code aren't equivalent, with the first producing very strange (and incorrect results).

```
-- Method 1
highestElement1([],A,A).
highestElement1([H|T],A,Max) :-
                    H > A,
                    highestElement1(T,H,Max);
                    highestElement1(T,A,Max).

-- Method 2
highestElement2([],A,A).
highestElement2([H|T],A,Max) :-
                    H > A,
                    highestElement2(T,H,Max).

highestElement2([H|T],A,Max) :-
                    H =< A,
                    highestElement2(T,A,Max).
```

From my understanding, they should be identical, as I believe(d) that pattern matching and 'or' are basically syntatic sugar for one another. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2):

Method1 is actually equivalent to:

```
highestElement2([],A,A).

highestElement2([H|T],A,Max) :-
    H > A,
    highestElement2(T,H,Max).

highestElement2([H|T],A,Max) :-
    highestElement2(T,A,Max).
```

This is due to the relative priorities of the `(,)/2` and `(;)/2` operators:

```
| ?- current_op(Priority, Type, ',').

Priority = 1000
Type = xfy

yes
| ?- current_op(Priority, Type, ';').

Priority = 1100
Type = xfy

yes
```

I.e. the second clause of `highestElement1` is parsed as:

```
highestElement1([H|T],A,Max) :-
    (H > A, highestElement1(T,H,Max))
    ;
    highestElement1(T,A,Max).
```

One way to visualize how a term is parsed if we're not sure about operator notation is to use the standard `write_canonical/1` built-in predicate:

```
| ?- write_canonical((a :- b,c; d)).
:-(a,;(','(b,c),d))

(1 ms) yes
```

The output tells us that we have a compound term with name `:-` and two arguments, `a` and `;(','(b,c),d)`. The second argument is also a compound term with name `;` and two arguments, `','(b,c)` and `d`.